# Adding a dividing line across all columns in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In my grid, I display my items in 3 columns.

I want to draw a red divider between the 3 columns.

I tried to add a right border to the cells.

**The problem:** When the number of items is 4 (or 7 or 10 and so on) the right border of the 5th cell in the grid is missing, since there is no item in this grid cell. I want the border between the 2nd and 3rd column to reach till the bottom of the grid.

In different screen resolutions the number of columns may be different (2 or 4).

I want to handle this using CSS only (with media query). I don't want any HTML or JS involved.

```css
ul {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
   grid-column-gap: 10px;
   width: 500px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   list-style: none;
}
    
li {
   border-right: 2px solid red;
}
    
li:nth-child(3n) {
   border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> A </li>
  <li> B </li>
  <li> C </li>
  <li> D </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rh5ru19r/6/

Is there another way to draw a divider between the columns?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you ask for doesn't make much sense. You either want to display a border on an item that doesn't exist, or you want an item to extend its border if the element below it is missing and the row below exists. None of which are possible. A decent resolve would be to add `li:last-child { border-right: none;}` to your CSS. But that's different from what you asked for.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I want to draw a column divider between the cells, like a table.
I updated my question.
My first comment explains why I don't want to use a HTML table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're open to using media queries, and the number of columns is known (2, 3 or 4), you may be able to use the background color of the grid and pseudo-elements to make your layout work.

[**revised jsfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2cbty8x/4/)

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(21%, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;    
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

@media ( max-width: 700px ) {
  ul { grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr)); }
  ul::before { content: ""; background-color: white; order: 1; }
  ul::after  { content: ""; background-color: white; order: 2; }  
}

@media ( max-width: 400px ) {
  ul { grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(40%, 1fr)); }
  ul::before { content: none; }
  ul::after  { content: none; }  
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> A </li>
  <li> B </li>
  <li> C </li>
  <li> D </li>
</ul>
```